# ReactJs - ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

After some changes on an existing component, I am having trouble in the jest tests.
Basically, I added a call on a componentDidMount function to a function that does a "fetch" internally and now I am getting an error when running jest tests

[image]

fetch is being called in the utils/index.ts and this one is being called from the MyComponent.tsx

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.actions.requestLoadA();
    this.props.actions.requestLoadB();

    // Problematic call HERE
    this.getXPTOStatuses("something");  
}

getXPTOStatuses = (something: string) => {
            HttpUtility.get(`/api/getXPTOStatuses?param=${something}`)
                .then(response => handleFetchErrors(response))
                .then(data => {
                    // ....
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // show the error message to the user -> `Could not load participant statuses. Error: '${error.message}'`                
                });
        }
```

and the get(...)

```
public static get = (url: string) => fetch(url, { method: "GET", headers: { Accept: "application/json" }, credentials: "same-origin" });
```

and the jest test in the cause:
MyContainer.test.tsx

```
describe("Risk Import Container Tests", () => {
    let props: MyContainerProps;

    beforeEach(() => {
        props = initialProps;
    });

    it("Matches the snapshot", () => {
        const props = initialProps;        

        const tree = shallow(<MyContainer {...props} />);
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please show the contents of the `getXPTOStatuses` function, especially where you use `fetch`.

Comment: AFAIK, `shallow` calls `componentDidMount` by default.  So, what is the issue?

Comment: As I mentioned in the description, I am getting "ReferenceError: fetch is not defined" when running the jest tests

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38317062/bypass-fetch-call-in-react-component?rq=1 . Your problem is clear, fetch is not being initialized properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Enzymes's `shallow` function calls `componentDidMount`.  So, this would naturally call through to where `fetch` is used.

You have 2 options, mock `fetch` somehow.

Or use the `shallow` option `disableLifecycleMethods` to disable the call to `componentDidMount`.